# StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException:The JSON-RPC connection withthe remote party was lost before the request could complete. this execption occured

Tags: c#, .net, azure, automation, rdp

I am executing an automation script on Azure-VM. it is 8GB RAM and Window 10,
My automation framework is. Net-Selenium-C#-Nunit. during execution, it throws an exception
"StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. this exception occurred "

Suggest solution